# How far can we track ionic based spaceships if antenna fails

Tags: optics, thermal-radiation, ionization-energy

Suppose we send an ionic based spaceship and all the antennas are broken on launch,
suppose the spaceship destination is another solar system.

Obviously we can track it with optical telescopes,
but i think maybe we can track it with another radiation the spaceships emits, maybe heat, the ionized particles,...
So my questions are:
How far can we track it?

Answer (score 1):

Not very far at all, unless you put sensors in space as well.

Light, and radio, is great for tracking things in space because the atmosphere is transparent at most useful wavelengths. So that means you can built a telescope down here on "the bottom" and still see things in space.

In contrast, none of the other possible things you mention would make it to the ground. The fuel ions would be washed away by the solar wind very quickly, never to be seen again. Some of the radiation you might see if it used an RTG wouldn't make it past the most upper layers of the atmosphere.

The engine itself gives off some light, but I don't think it would be much more than a couple of thousand watts, at the outside. Sunlight is about 1200W/m^2 in space, so not much more than the natural reflection.

So I'd say it would start to get really hard once you started getting past the moon, depending on the size of course.

One thing you could do is use a retroflector and sweep a laser across the area until you see the reflection. That definitely works on the Moon, but I'm not confident enough to say if it would work as far as Mars.

Comment: ok, maybe in some decades we may develop some "gravitacional telescopes" and then open the most powerfull way of tracking ever.

Comment: Such a thing already exists! Unfortunately, gravitation is the weakest force, so the signal will be even weaker. We can barely see the signal when two black holes collide, so seeing a space probe is going to be difficult. Maybe what we need is the Macroscope!